# drawerNavigator header not showing

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to nest a DrawerNavigator inside my StackNavigator using a few of the methods found on this page:

https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/131

My app loads, but it is not displaying anything in the header bar. It should have a title and an image that, when clicked, shows the drawer menu.

If anyone has gotten something like this to work, can you please help?  Thanks!

Here is my app.js:

```
import Drawer from './DrawerMenu';

const diceRoller = StackNavigator({
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Drawer: { screen: Drawer }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('diceRoller', () => diceRoller);

export { diceRoller }
```

DrawerMenu.js:

```
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { TouchableHighlight, Image } from 'react-native';
import MenuScreen from './MenuScreen';
import React from 'react';

const getDrawerItem = navigation => (
  <TouchableHighlight>
      <Image source={require('./images/menubars.png')} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
    onPress={() => {
      if (navigation.state.index === 0) {
        navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen');
      } else {
        navigation.navigate('DrawerClose');
      }
    }}
  </TouchableHighlight>
);

const getNavigationOptionsWithAction = (title, backgroundColor, color, headerLeft) => ({
  title,
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor,
  },
  headerTitleStyle: {
    color,
  },
  headerTintColor: color,
  headerLeft,
});

const getDrawerConfig = (drawerWidth, drawerPosition) => ({
  drawerWidth,
  drawerPosition,
});

const Drawer = DrawerNavigator ({
    MenuScreen: { screen: MenuScreen }
}, getDrawerConfig(300, 'left'));

Drawer.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => getNavigationOptionsWithAction('Menu', 'blue', 'white',  getDrawerItem(navigation));

export default Drawer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight.html) that touchable highlight should have only one child.
But you have passed `onPress` as an attribute inside it. That might be the issue.

The react native docs mention this syntax for TouchableHighlight.
If you wish to use more than one child elements then wrap them in a View.

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={this._onPressButton}>
      <Image
        style={styles.button}
        source={require('./myButton.png')}
      />
    </TouchableHighlight>
```